# java web based chat application

Tags: jquery, jsp, gwt

I wanted to develop a small web based chat application. Currently I have developed by using Applets. 
So can I create the application by using JSP and servlets without including the applets. Probably I would like to use JQuery or GWT in my web application.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can implement a chat with the JSP and the jQuery library. jQuery provides a rich [set of methods for AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) capabilities. But in my opinion GWT is suitable the best for implementing multi-featured chat. It's ideal for applications based on AJAX and which have a rich user interface. You can greatly simplify development your application and AJAX-implementation using very convenient feature of [Remote procedure call](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.1/tutorial/RPC) communications between client-side and server-side.

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/ServerPushFAQ) you can find answers to some questions from the server push, handling of threads and safety issues on the server side. This is necessarily need you to develop a chat application.

And here's an interesting example with GWT implementation of chat: [first](http://tcninja.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-create-simple-chat-using-gwt-and.html) and [second](http://tcninja.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-create-simple-chat-using-gwt-and_15.html) part.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a web based chat application using jsp and servlets without using applets. [here](http://www.web-tech-india.com/software/jsp_chat.php) is one example. You can download the application and [source](http://www.web-tech-india.com/software/validate.php?fileName=chatsrc.zip) as well. Have a look at it and use JQuery where ever necessary.